# Problem getting value of an HTML text input using $_GET in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a little website I am building to help me learn HTML/PHP/Javascript. On this website I have a Leaflet map where I display the locations of tweets I have stored in a postgreSQL/POSTGIS database. I had this working when I hardcoded the SQL query into my PHP code, but now I wanted to add a feature that allows the user to provide text input which will be used to query one of the columns of the database (hashtag column). Here is where I am running into problems, as I cannot seem to get the input text to work in my query. I am using $_GET to pass the value from the input text box to the PHP page which uses that value to perform the query. However, when I use echo to see what value $_GET['input'] was returning, I found that it returns some HTML string:

[[image: Value of $_GET'input']

For the website I have created 4 scripts. The first is the main page which contains my HTML code, the second is a javascript code which creates the leaflet map and defines a function when people click on the map features, the third is another javascript code which uses ajax to get data from the database (by interacting with the 4th script) and loading them to my leaflet map.

Below are the four pages:
Page 1, main HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Leaftet Map</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <h1> Welcome to my Leaftlet Map </h1>
        <p> Search for a City and if we have tweets for it they will display on the map! (Currently only #Tokyo and #Berlin are supported) </p>
        
        <!-- insert to input box here -->
        <form name="input" method="get">
            <input type='text' value="#Berlin" id='input' name='input'/>
            <input type='button' value='Search hashtag' id='search' onclick="loadData();"/>
        </form>
        
        <div id = "mapid"></div>
        <!--If we put the script before the div, then the script will run but div doesnt exist yet, so the map won't show up!-->
        
        <script src="./mapLoad.js"></script>
        <script>
            function loadData() {
            var value = $("#input").val();
            if (value.length != 0) {
                $.getScript("ajax.js")
            
                }
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Page 2, Leaflet map creation:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 5);
            
L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=wq2dobtMr2Zc1pJFS7rB', 
            {attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
            }
            ).addTo(mymap);

// create a function to perform when someone mouses on each feature
function func_name (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.tweet)
};
```

Page 3, Ajax script:

```
// JQuery script that runs the load from database script

$.ajax({url:'loadFromDB.php', // loadfromDB.php is the fourth script/page (see below)
    success: function(response){
        feats = JSON.parse(response);
        L.geoJSON(feats, {onEachFeature: func_name}).addTo(mymap);
        
        
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
        alert("ERROR: "+error);
        
    }
    
}
);
```

Page 4, PHP script to connect to DB, query, and return result

```
<?php 
// ***********************Connect to the database***********************
try{
    $myPDO = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=PostGIS_DB","postgres","password");   
}
catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
}



    // ***********************Define function***********************
    function getData($input){
        // Query the polygon table
        $result = $myPDO->query("SELECT json_build_object(
                                'type', 'Feature',
                                'geometry', ST_AsGeoJSON(geog)::JSONB,
                                'properties', to_jsonb(row) - 'gid' - 'geog'
                                ) FROM (SELECT *
                                        FROM tweets_point
                                        WHERE tweets_point.hashtag = '".$input."'
                                        UNION ALL
                                        SELECT *
                                        FROM tweets_poly
                                        WHERE tweets_poly.hashtag = '".$input."')
                                    
                                row;");
        // Loop through rows of the result and append to the feature collection
        $features = array();
        foreach($result AS $rows){
            //since $row['jsonb_build_object'] is in json format but is currently wrapped in a string we decode the json from the string
            $j = json_decode($rows['jsonb_build_object']);
            array_push($features, $j);
        }
        $feature_collect=["type"=>"FeatureCollection", "features"=>$features];
        
        echo json_encode($feature_collect);
    }
    
    
    // ***********************Get the input value to display tweets***********************
    $input = '';
    if(isset($_GET['input'])){ 
        $input = $_GET['input'];  
        getData($input); 
    };
    
?>
```

But as I stated above, I think the problem comes down to the  code I have written for the text input and the $_GET['input'] variable. Maybe someone has some ideas?

Comment: The HTML is an error message. On line 50 you're using `input` as an index where the array does not have that index. Check that line.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Was enough to get me unstuck and continue debugging, works now. Turns out I was using $_GET in the wrong way and it was just an empty array.